# device not showing css changes using local server

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, media-queries

I am developing a project for iPhone. The problem I have is I am not seeing the changes I do on my css appear on my iPhone. I am using MAMP.

If I change the html it does show on the device and the changes on my css do show on the computer screen if I reduce the size of the browser to the media query requirements to mimic the iPhone screen.

How can I force my css to update on my device and why does the html update on the phone but not the css?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: _“and why does the html update on the phone but not the css?”_ - because caching exists ... suggest you implement a simple cache buster solution, so that your CSS always gets loaded “fresh”, for the development phase.

Comment: This is probably a caching issue. Try adding a question mark and a few characters behind the link of your CSS file. <link href="mycss.css?v=1"

Comment: The code is very long. I don't think there is a problem in the code. The changes in the css show on the computer screen when I reduce the size of the browser, so the code works.

Comment: so how do i force my css to get loaded "fresh"

Comment: Depends upon the browser you are using.  This might help : http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-clear-cache-on-your-iphone-or-ipad-3609079/